# AttributeError: module 'pycaret.anomaly' has no attribute 'compare_models'

Tags: python, pycaret

I want to compare profiles for all the pycaret anomaly models, using anomaly.compare_models():

```
anomaly.compare_models()
```

but getting error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pycaret.anomaly' has no attribute 'compare_models'
```

How to resolve this?